# How to import a module from a directory?

Tags: python, python-import, sys, sys.path

On my system I have two versions of Python (to call them I type `python` and `python2` in the command line). When I use the first version of Python, I cannot import `sklearn` module but I can do it in the second version of Python.

I would like to use the first version of python (because other modules are available there) and, at the same time, I would like to be able to `import sklearn` from this version of Python.

My solution was to use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('location_of_the_sklearn_module')
```

To find the location of the `sklearn` module I started a python session (using the second version of python, in which sklearn works). The I type:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__file__
```

As a result I got:

```
/home/name/my_name/numpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.pyc
```

In the session of the first version of Python I tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/name/my_name/numpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn')
import sklearn
```

Unfortunately it did not work. As a result I got: `ImportError: No module named sklearn`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong and if it is possible to reach the goal in the way I try?

Comment: If your first `Python` is actually Python 3, then as far as I know, sklearn does not support it yet.

Comment: @voithos, both versions of python are 2.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing packages, you need to add the parent directory of the package to `PYTHONPATH`, not the package directory itself, so just change...

```
sys.path.append('/home/name/my_name/numpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn')
```

...to...

```
sys.path.append('/home/name/my_name/numpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

...although it may not necessarily import correctly in Python 3.x.